# Using a model to compare name and surname

Tags: machine-learning, gensim

I have names of employees saved in a text file. I processed the file and compared a name that already exist.
When I checked using most_similar method, I found that it returns totally unrelated name even if the exact same name exist in the corpus.

```
import gensim

training_file='todel.txt'
mylist=list()
with open(training_file, encoding="iso-8859-1") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        mylist.append(gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(line), [i]))

model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=50, min_count=2, epochs=55)
model.build_vocab(mylist)

inferred_vector=model.infer_vector(['aakash', 'prakash', 'patel'])

sims = model.docvecs.most_similar([inferred_vector])

' '.join(mylist[sims[0][0]].words)
```

How do I correctly train the data to return (closely) matching names?

Comment: How do you define similarity in names?

Comment: "aakash" and "akash" are similar. This does not seem to be possible. My question is why does it return totally unrelated words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define similarity in terms of *edit distance*, i.e. how similar two **strings** are.

x2vec models define similarity in terms of *semantic closeness*, i.e. how similar two **meanings** are, computed through machine learning and co-occurrence statistics.

In other words, you're using a sledgehammer to kill a fly. Look into [tools for computing string distance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein) instead:

```python
from Levenshtein import distance
string1 = 'aakash'
string2 = 'akash'
string3 = 'konstantinos'
print(distance(string1, string2))
1
print(distance(string1, string3))
11
```